# Dig into classification report

Tags: python, classification, metrics, precision-recall

I do have a large dataset having 2 features but lots of samples. I am trying to classify them through supervised classifiers. My goal is to achieve which classes have precision or recall lower than 60%. Is there any specific script that i can run to get me class numbers with precision and recall lower than 60%??

The code that i have applied so far is like below but it is not dynamic. 
I can get the report of classification with this line: "print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))" 
But i have 200 class labels and i only want to pick ones with precision and recall lower than 60%.

```
scores = cross_val_score(estimator= DecisionTreeClassifier(), 
                         X=X_train, 
                         y=y_train, 
                         cv=5,
                         n_jobs=-1)
print('CV accuracy scores: %s' % scores)
print('CV accuracy: %.3f +/- %.3f' % (
                                       np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)))

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print('Test Accuracy: %.3f' % model.score(X_test, y_test))
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```